# UK Toursit Visit visa Refused

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

30-day UK tourist visa rejected. Since i have booked the flights and hotels i am 
planning to reapply. So can i reapply again and which are the additional documents required ?

Reason for rejection ( from Embassy note):

> i have refused your application for visit because i am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of Appendix V: Immigration Rules for Visitor because
>
> You have stated that you are a senior engineer for Company £ 625 per month after tax and you have evidenced this with Payslips and an employment letter.
>   You stated that the trip will personally cost you £ 4000 . As a evidence of your personal finances have provided the following bank details in your name.
>
> Total bank balance £ 6500 ( Salary account and savings account combined).
>
> How ever i note recent deposits have been credited to each of the bank accounts provided. Of particular note is a deposit of £3700 credited to account xxxxxx on 22/7/16. From the documents provided, the origin of these fund is unclear and deposit are inconsistent with the transnational history shown. I am not satisfied that the money is genuinely available to your exclusive use. Deposits in the account bear little relation to your stated income and i do not discount the possibility that an attempt has been made to provide an enhanced image of your financial circumstances for the purpose of this application.
>   i have therefore refused your application with paragraph v4.2 (a) and (c) and (e) of the immigration Rules.

The amount £3700 is credited from my father account it can be clearly seen from  the statement that i have submitted. He got the money from local saving scheme and i am paying monthly by cash for 4 years. I don't any proof to show the source of that money.

Please tell me which are the additional documents required for reapplying ?

Comment: This is straight-forward funds parking and provenance. It's a very routine type of refusal. Please read the linked answer for all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are planning to spend half a year's income on the trip, before cost of living is accounted for and presumably also before taxes. That is highly unusual and requires explanation.

If I understand you right, you took a loan from your father that will take four years to repay. That is not normal for a tourist, either. The UK does not believe you, but they did not come out and said you lied because the relation of income and travel costs looks bad enough without that addition.

If you really want to travel to the UK, it might be helpful to [consult a practitioner](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/pages/find-immigration-advice.html) with an established practice area in visit visas.

The controlling technical reference for your grounds (i.e., V 4.2 a+c+e) is in [Appendix V of the rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules).